# About the factorization of $\,q^{p-1}+(p-1)^q$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Let's consider the arithmetic function $\,f(p,q)=q^{p-1}+(p-1)^q\,$ where $\,p\,$ and $\,q\,$ are prime numbers and $\,p\ne q$.

Using Fermat's little theorem it's easy to prove that $\;f(p,q)\equiv 0\mod p$.

In the case $\,p=5\,$ we have, for example:

$$7^4+4^7=18785=5\cdot13\cdot17^2$$
$$11^4+4^{11}=4208945=5\cdot13^2\cdot17\cdot293$$
$$13^4+4^{13}=67137425=5^2\cdot37\cdot181\cdot401$$

We note, in this case, that the prime factors of $\,f(p,q)\,$ are all of the form $\,4m+1$.

This should be a consequence of the fact that $\,q^4+4^q=(q^2)^2+(2^q)^2$.

**I ask for a formal proof eventually extensible to the more general case $\,p=2^k+1\;(17, 257, ...)$.**

Many thanks.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563599/finding-a-rescription-function-of-prime-numbers), a few hours ago. For $f(q)=q$ and $f(p)=p-1$ one side is $q^{p-1}+(p-1)^q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider $p,q\neq 2$ prime number. $p=2^{2k}+1$ than you can easy write
\begin{equation}
f(p,q)=(q^{2^{2k-1}})^2+(2^{kq})^2
\end{equation}
that means that $f(p,q)$ is a sum of squares. It's a well known fact that if a number can be written as a sum of squares that it's of the form $4m+1$ for some integer $m$. More than that every prime that divides a sum of squares can be written in that form and that answer your question. The results I use are easy consequences of the prime splitting in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: when i assume that $q=2^{2k}+1$ there is no loss of generalization because the if a prime number is in the form $2^k+1$ then $k$ must be a power of $2$.

Comment: you're right $p=2^{2k}+1$ (I'll correct the original post). If you choose $p=3$ and $q=5$ you have $f(p,q)=5^2+2^5= 57=19\cdot 3$ and this is a counterexample